# Jordan Lemma or ML bound

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
Question want to find contour integral from this, from negative infinity to positive infinity.

I used upper semi ciecle as the contour.
But not sure if I am correct with the arc part.
I let it vanished by using Jordan Lemma with following
[image]
so i got
[image]
and so i let f(z) vanish  by
[image]
as R goes to infinity.
So arc part will vanish.

Am I correct with the steps?

Comment: Jordan's Lemma requires $e^{iz}$, not $e^z$; do you intend the former? The function $e^z$ will not decrease on either half plane (think about $z = i * t$ for $t \in \mathbb R$) and trivially blows up along the real line. There is no way your integral, as written, can converge

Comment: sorry it's e^iz, forgot to put the i on it

Comment: Ok, then Jordan's Lemma says the integral on the outer arc is zero since the integrand is of the form $e^{iaz} \mathcal{O}(z^{-1})$

Comment: Hi, i am not sure how to apply jordan lemma, and I had edited the question. Am I right for this?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: thanks so much!!!!